# Bolts async framework methods not recognized

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, bolts-framework

In my swift iOS app I installed the bolts framework, and in the bridging header file I got this

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

So it's supposed to work.
However, I can't get access to any methods from this framework, such as  findAsync or continueWithSuccessBlock. They are not recognized.
Am I missing the point ? How to have bolts method frameworks recognized ?

Comment: you did this step? : `Next you need to add it to your target’s build settings:In Xcode, if you go into the build settings for your target, and scroll all the way down you’ll find a “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section.
Set “Objective-C Bridging Header” to <#PROJECT_NAME>/Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: Yes I got this: I have several others frameworks in the bridge files (Facebook, parse...) and they work correctly

Comment: download it again and try to reImport it.

Comment: Won't help. Still unrecognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly found that the syntax is different that all what is documented.
Documentation states that to access BFTask on query, you must type:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Student")
findAsync(query).continueWithSuccessBlock
```

Well it turns out that "findAsync" does not exist on my version ?!
Instead, I can access it with:

```
query.findObjectsinBackground()
```

This returns a BFTask, and then I can access the other Bolts code such as continueWithBlock.

Answer (score 1):

[Bolts documentation](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/blob/master/Readme.md) states that you need to implement findAsync: yourself.

> For the examples in this doc, assume there are async versions of some
>   common Parse methods, called saveAsync: and findAsync: which return a
>   Task. In a later section, we'll show how to define these functions
>   yourself.

You create your own "Async" functions following [these examples](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/blob/master/Readme.md#creating-async-methods). Note this section's last sentence:

> It's similarly easy to create saveAsync:, findAsync: or deleteAsync:

Here's an implementation of findAsync:

```
func findAsync(query:PFQuery) -> BFTask {
    var task = BFTaskCompletionSource()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            task.setResult(objects)
        } else {
            task.setError(error)
        }
    }
    return task.task
}
```